# Date/Time formatting with variables containing day of the week

Tags: r, datetime, format

I'm trying to format a date column that contains the day of the week. When I try to format it using my usual method my time is always 00:00. Here is an example:

```
a <- c(1:6)
Date <- c("Tuesday, 05 December 2012 05:00","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 06:55","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 07:10",
       "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 10:23", "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 11:43","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 13:04")
b <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If I try to change the format using this code:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(DateTime = format(as.Date(Date, format = "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M"), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
```

I get a response where the hours and minutes are always 00:00. I believe this has something to with the date not being POSIXct/POSIXlt format, but I'm not sure.

```
  a                            Date b         DateTime
1 1 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 05:00 0 05-12-2012 00:00
2 2 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 06:55 0 05-12-2012 00:00
3 3 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 07:10 0 05-12-2012 00:00
4 4 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 10:23 1 05-12-2012 00:00
5 5 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 11:43 1 05-12-2012 00:00
6 6 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 13:04 1 05-12-2012 00:00
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date`, because the standard Date class does not support time. Note also that weekday names are locale dependent, so it may not work on all systems.

Comment: A small remark: Do not use function names to store variables, e.g. `c <- c()` or `list <- list()` is considered bad practice, use `myVec <- c()`, `my_vec <- c()`, ... instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here another approach:

```r
# data 
b <- c("Tuesday, 05 December 2012 05:00","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 06:55","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 07:10",
       "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 10:23", "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 11:43","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 13:04")

# remove everything before first digit
b <- sub("^\\D+", "", b)

# use ydm_hm() from {lubridate}
library(lubridate)
ydm_hm(b)
#> [1] "2005-12-20 05:00:00 UTC" "2005-12-20 06:55:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2005-12-20 07:10:00 UTC" "2005-12-20 10:23:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2005-12-20 11:43:00 UTC" "2005-12-20 13:04:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**EDIT**

To be in line with your style:

```r
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("Tuesday, 05 December 2012 05:00","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 06:55","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 07:10",
       "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 10:23", "Tuesday, 05 December 2012 11:43","Tuesday, 05 December 2012 13:04")
c <- c("0","0","0","1","1","1")

df1 <- data.frame(a, b, c, 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 |>
  mutate(Datetime = ydm_hm(sub("^\\D+", "", b))
         ) |>
  rename(Date = b)

head(df1)
#>   a                            Date c            Datetime
#> 1 1 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 05:00 0 2005-12-20 05:00:00
#> 2 2 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 06:55 0 2005-12-20 06:55:00
#> 3 3 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 07:10 0 2005-12-20 07:10:00
#> 4 4 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 10:23 1 2005-12-20 10:23:00
#> 5 5 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 11:43 1 2005-12-20 11:43:00
#> 6 6 Tuesday, 05 December 2012 13:04 1 2005-12-20 13:04:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

could be a locale issue?

```
#store current locale, ans change to En
orig_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English.UTF-8")
as.POSIXct(df1$b, format = "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M")
#reset locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", orig_locale)

# [1] "2012-12-05 05:00:00 CET" "2012-12-05 06:55:00 CET" "2012-12-05 07:10:00 CET" "2012-12-05 10:23:00 CET"
# [5] "2012-12-05 11:43:00 CET" "2012-12-05 13:04:00 CET"
```

Comment: This is a good idea but not my issue!

Comment: Why not? Worked perfectly on a German Win2k system with `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`.